# NgRx EffectsModule imports group

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am trying to understand if it's possible to combine/group all ngrx effects into a single object. What I really want to ask is if exists something equivalent with the ActionReducerMap (which groups the reducers) for the effects.
In `app.module.ts`, in my `imports` array I have the following:

```
...
StoreModule.forRoot(fromApp.appReducer),
EffectsModule.forRoot([DemoEffects, ModuleOneEffects, ModuleTwoEffects]),
...
```

Is there any way to make it prettier and group `DemoEffects, ModuleOneEffects, ModuleTwoEffects`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but you could do the following with the spread operator. Have a separate file with your effects:

```
export const miscEffects = [
  DemoEffects
];

export const moduleEffects = [
  ModuleOneEffects,
  ModuleTwoEffects
];
```

Which you can then import in your `NgModule`:

```
StoreModule.forRoot(fromApp.appReducer),
EffectsModule.forRoot([
  ...miscEffects ,
  ...moduleEffects,
  ...reallyCoolGroupedEffects
])
```

Comment: Actually, I was looking for a function equivalent with the ActionReducerMap but for the Effects.